# PHP string from SQL database shown as plain text

Tags: php, sql

Forgive a beginner's question -- I am trying to call a PHP command from an SQL database using another command, but the web page shows the command as plain text instead.

For instance, my command on the page is `<?php echo $row_rsLeftColumn['code']; ?>` and that calls this item in the SQL database: `<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>`. However, the web page doesn't display "Hello World" even though I can see the line in the source -- so, the line has been successfully extracted from the SQL database, the page is just treating it as plain text.

When I add the line into the web page directly, it works as expected, so the trouble doesn't seem to be that PHP is mis-configured on the web server; rather it's something about the page not recognizing PHP as such when it calls it from the SQL database, even though it recognizes it directly on the page.

Any assistance you can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: i'm glad it did.... think of the security problems you might have otherwise.. search for the php command `eval`

Comment: almost always a bad idea to store php in the db

Comment: do not store PHP or HTML in the database

Comment: @Blaine There is no inherent problem with storing HTML in a database, the problem, if any, is in the *usage*; although, it should only be done as required and, as always, *correct usage* is required (e.g. escaping, perhaps, or breakdown/reconstruction for validation).

Comment: @pst There may be no inherent problem, but where I'm from, a database is for data, not HTML that can be generated via PHP while one is retrieving the data

Comment: @Blaine Or the HTML could be from another source.. guard generalized statements ;-)

Comment: In the comments to answers you've asked about security: and indeed, this *can* be an issue with `eval`. So then some followup questions 1. Why needing to execute stored PHP code required? 2. Can the use of `eval` be avoided? 3. If not, how can the security footprint be reduced?

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP code in the database that you wish to extract and execute, you need to use [eval()](http://php.net/eval) to run it.

Take caution with eval as it doesn't perform any checks on the code so if end users can enter code, they can write any malicious code they want.  Read over the docs on eval thoroughly before using it if you must.  And take note that you must remove the `<?php ?>` tags from the code before calling eval.

Comment: I would emphasis ".. [**does not prevent**] **malicious code** .."; I do not trust *any* of my users this much -- to allow *their code* to run under *my security principal* -- and I would suggest that others take a similar view.

Answer (score 0):

It is coming out of the database as a string. Right now you are pulling it out and telling it to echo. You should use the eval() function.

```
<?php eval($row_rsLeftColumn['code']); ?>
```

Comment: However, I would **not** recommend/use an approach like this. There are *generally* cleaner approaches, and using this `eval` approach, depending upon the data source and security of such, can allow malicious code to be injected.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. I am trying -- maybe misguidedly -- to call a combination of HTML and PHP from an SQL database -- other areas of the same page call just HTML from the database, but this is a specific instance where it needs to call a PHP line for a third-party plugin.

The code coming from the SQL database is something like this:

`<div class=”sample”>

<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>

</div>`

I tried `<?php eval($row_rsLeftColumn['code']); ?>` and received `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'`. 

Again, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't reply in the comments yet...

`eval()` expects PHP code, so if your string starts with HTML you will need to prepend it with `?>`.

```
<?php eval('?>' . $row_rsLeftColumn['code']); ?>
```

Comment: Now it's working fine -- thanks! But I'm concerned about the suggestions that eval() might cause a security issue. There is no outside-user input in this part of the site -- it is just calling PHP records supplied by our internal database. Is there a "more secure" command I should use than eval(), or will this be OK?